# How to use the querylist object in Django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Initially i had this code

`(r'^list/fixed/$', list_detail.object_list, fixedList)`

In template i use

`{% for val in object_list %}`

It worked fine as i used Generic list

But now i want to write my own view which does same

```
 object_list = model.objects.all()
 return render_to_response('lists.html', object_list)
```

But its not working.

how can pass the same object list to template as in Generic View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`render_to_response()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) takes a dictionary of variables to use.

```
return render_to_response('lists.html', {'object_list': object_list})
```